# Wordpress multiple query_posts loops - pagination not working

Tags: wordpress

I have a set of posts that have all been assigned a year using a custom taxonomy.  Using query posts I want to be able to sort these posts so that posts from 2012 are shown first then the remainder are sorted alphabetically.

I have the example below working correctly, it first displays all of the posts that have a matching meta-value of 2012, then the second loop displays everything else exluding the posts from the first loop....

```
<?php query_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'project',
    'meta_key' => 'start_date_year',
    'meta_value' => '2012'
    ));
    $ids = array();
?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<p>This is from Loop 1 - <?php the_title(); ?> - <?php the_id(); ?></p>
<?php $ids[]= $post->ID; ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php query_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'project',
    'post__not_in' => $ids
    ));
?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<p>This is from Loop 2 - <?php the_title(); ?> - <?php the_id(); ?></p>

<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php pagination(); ?>
```

The only issue I have left now is pagination, it is showing 2 pages but each one contains the same result...

Answer (score 2):

I would run two loops collect the ID's of the posts from the first loop in an array and exclude them from the second array by adding this into your second wp_query $args

alike so...

```
'post__not_in' => $array_variables_from_first_loop,
```

Comment: That's the route I've decided on going down so thanks for the suggestion.  I am, as expected, struggling to implement it though!  I have updated the original post with where I am at so far...